# Dependency Injection not working when I using taghelper to trigger controller

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I am using tag helper to activate the controller but when I use specifically asp-controller and asp-action it doesn't help me to enable dependency injection service and
and the website crashed,

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Application.Interfaces.Repositories.ILessonService' while attempting to activate 'API.Controllers.LessonController'

but when I use href in `<a href=" ">...</a>` then works normally

```
<a class="collapse-item" asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Lesson">Reading</a>
<a class="collapse-item" href="/Lesson/Index">Listening</a>
```

This is whole view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>SB Admin 2 - Dashboard</title>

    <!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
    <link href="~/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i"
        rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
    <link href="~/css/sb-admin-2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body id="page-top">

    <!-- Page Wrapper -->
    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <ul class="navbar-nav bg-gradient-primary sidebar sidebar-dark accordion" id="accordionSidebar">

            <!-- Sidebar - Brand -->
            <a class="sidebar-brand d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" href="/Home/Index">
                <div class="sidebar-brand-icon rotate-n-15">
                    <i class="fas fa-laugh-wink"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="sidebar-brand-text mx-3">SB Admin <sup>2</sup></div>
            </a>

            <!-- Divider -->
            <hr class="sidebar-divider my-0">

            <!-- Nav Item - Dashboard -->
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/Home/Index">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
                    <span>Dashboard</span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <!-- Divider -->
            <hr class="sidebar-divider">

            <!-- Heading -->
            <div class="sidebar-heading">
                Interface
            </div>

            <!-- Nav Item - Pages Collapse Menu -->
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo"
                   aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-cog"></i>
                    <span>Admin</span>
                </a>
                <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
                    <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
                        <h6 class="collapse-header">Người dùng</h6>
                        <a class="collapse-item" asp-controller="User" asp-action="Index">Quản lý người dùng</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="cards.html">Cards</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>

            <!-- Nav Item - Utilities Collapse Menu -->
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseUtilities"
                   aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseUtilities">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-wrench"></i>
                    <span>Giáo Viên</span>
                </a>
                <div id="collapseUtilities" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingUtilities"
                     data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
                    <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
                        <h6 class="collapse-header">Lesson</h6>
                        <a class="collapse-item" asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Lesson">Reading</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="/Lesson/Index">Listening</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="/Teacher/Speaking">Speaking</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="/Teacher/Writting">writting</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="/Teacher/Test">Testing</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <!-- Nav Item - Utilities Collapse Menu -->

            <!-- Divider -->
            <hr class="sidebar-divider">

            <!-- Heading -->
            <div class="sidebar-heading">
                Addons
            </div>

            <!-- Nav Item - Pages Collapse Menu -->
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsePages"
                   aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapsePages">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-folder"></i>
                    <span>Pages</span>
                </a>
                <div id="collapsePages" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingPages" data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
                    <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
                        <h6 class="collapse-header">Login Screens:</h6>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="login.html">Login</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="register.html">Register</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="forgot-password.html">Forgot Password</a>
                        <div class="collapse-divider"></div>
                        <h6 class="collapse-header">Other Pages:</h6>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="404.html">404 Page</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="blank.html">Blank Page</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>

            <!-- Nav Item - Charts -->
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="charts.html">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-chart-area"></i>
                    <span>Charts</span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <!-- Nav Item - Tables -->
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="tables.html">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-table"></i>
                    <span>Tables</span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <!-- Divider -->
            <hr class="sidebar-divider d-none d-md-block">

            <!-- Sidebar Toggler (Sidebar) -->
            <div class="text-center d-none d-md-inline">
                <button class="rounded-circle border-0" id="sidebarToggle"></button>
            </div>

            <!-- Sidebar Message -->
            <div class="sidebar-card">
                <img class="sidebar-card-illustration mb-2" src="~/img/undraw_rocket.svg" alt="">
                <p class="text-center mb-2"><strong>SB Admin Pro</strong> is packed with premium features, components, and more!</p>
                <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" href="https://startbootstrap.com/theme/sb-admin-pro">Upgrade to Pro!</a>
            </div>

        </ul>
        <!-- End of Sidebar -->
        <!-- Content Wrapper -->
        <div id="content-wrapper" class="d-flex flex-column">

            <!-- Main Content -->
            <div id="content">

                <!-- Topbar -->
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-white topbar mb-4 static-top shadow">

                    <!-- Sidebar Toggle (Topbar) -->
                    <button id="sidebarToggleTop" class="btn btn-link d-md-none rounded-circle mr-3">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    </button>

                    <!-- Topbar Search -->
                    <form class="d-none d-sm-inline-block form-inline mr-auto ml-md-3 my-2 my-md-0 mw-100 navbar-search">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control bg-light border-0 small" placeholder="Search for..."
                                   aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
                                    <i class="fas fa-search fa-sm"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                    <!-- Topbar Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

                        <!-- Nav Item - Search Dropdown (Visible Only XS) -->
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow d-sm-none">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="searchDropdown" role="button"
                               data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <i class="fas fa-search fa-fw"></i>
                            </a>
                            <!-- Dropdown - Messages -->
                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right p-3 shadow animated--grow-in"
                                 aria-labelledby="searchDropdown">
                                <form class="form-inline mr-auto w-100 navbar-search">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control bg-light border-0 small"
                                               placeholder="Search for..." aria-label="Search"
                                               aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                                        <div class="input-group-append">
                                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
                                                <i class="fas fa-search fa-sm"></i>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <!-- Nav Item - Alerts -->
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow mx-1">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="alertsDropdown" role="button"
                               data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <i class="fas fa-bell fa-fw"></i>
                                <!-- Counter - Alerts -->
                                <span class="badge badge-danger badge-counter">3+</span>
                            </a>
                            <!-- Dropdown - Alerts -->
                            <div class="dropdown-list dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right shadow animated--grow-in"
                                 aria-labelledby="alertsDropdown">
                                <h6 class="dropdown-header">
                                    Alerts Center
                                </h6>
                                <a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
                                    <div class="mr-3">
                                        <div class="icon-circle bg-primary">
                                            <i class="fas fa-file-alt text-white"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="small text-gray-500">December 12, 2019</div>
                                        <span class="font-weight-bold">A new monthly report is ready to download!</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
                                    <div class="mr-3">
                                        <div class="icon-circle bg-success">
                                            <i class="fas fa-donate text-white"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="small text-gray-500">December 7, 2019</div>
                                        $290.29 has been deposited into your account!
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
                                    <div class="mr-3">
                                        <div class="icon-circle bg-warning">
                                            <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle text-white"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="small text-gray-500">December 2, 2019</div>
                                        Spending Alert: We've noticed unusually high spending for your account.
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item text-center small text-gray-500" href="#">Show All Alerts</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <!-- Nav Item - Messages -->
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow mx-1">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="messagesDropdown" role="button"
                               data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <i class="fas fa-envelope fa-fw"></i>
                                <!-- Counter - Messages -->
                                <span class="badge badge-danger badge-counter">7</span>
                            </a>
                            <!-- Dropdown - Messages -->
                            <div class="dropdown-list dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right shadow animated--grow-in"
                                 aria-labelledby="messagesDropdown">
                                <h6 class="dropdown-header">
                                    Message Center
                                </h6>
                                <a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
                                    <div class="dropdown-list-image mr-3">
                                        <img class="rounded-circle" src="~/img/undraw_profile_1.svg"
                                             alt="">
                                        <div class="status-indicator bg-success"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="font-weight-bold">
                                        <div class="text-truncate">
                                            Hi there! I am wondering if you can help me with a
                                            problem I've been having.
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="small text-gray-500">Emily Fowler · 58m</div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
                                    <div class="dropdown-list-image mr-3">
                                        <img class="rounded-circle" src="~/img/undraw_profile_2.svg"
                                             alt="">
                                        <div class="status-indicator"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="text-truncate">
                                            I have the photos that you ordered last month, how
                                            would you like them sent to you?
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="small text-gray-500">Jae Chun · 1d</div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
                                    <div class="dropdown-list-image mr-3">
                                        <img class="rounded-circle" src="~/img/undraw_profile_3.svg"
                                             alt="">
                                        <div class="status-indicator bg-warning"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="text-truncate">
                                            Last month's report looks great, I am very happy with
                                            the progress so far, keep up the good work!
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="small text-gray-500">Morgan Alvarez · 2d</div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
                                    <div class="dropdown-list-image mr-3">
                                        <img class="rounded-circle" src="https://source.unsplash.com/Mv9hjnEUHR4/60x60"
                                             alt="">
                                        <div class="status-indicator bg-success"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="text-truncate">
                                            Am I a good boy? The reason I ask is because someone
                                            told me that people say this to all dogs, even if they aren't good...
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="small text-gray-500">Chicken the Dog · 2w</div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item text-center small text-gray-500" href="#">Read More Messages</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <div class="topbar-divider d-none d-sm-block"></div>

                        <!-- Nav Item - User Information -->
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="userDropdown" role="button"
                               data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="mr-2 d-none d-lg-inline text-gray-600 small">Welcome</span>
                                <img class="img-profile rounded-circle"
                                     src="~/img/undraw_profile.svg">
                            </a>
                            <!-- Dropdown - User Information -->
                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right shadow animated--grow-in"
                                 aria-labelledby="userDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Profile/Index">
                                    <i class="fas fa-user fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>
                                    @User.Identity.Name
                                </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                    <i class="fas fa-cogs fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>
                                    Settings
                                </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                    <i class="fas fa-list fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>
                                    Activity Log
                                </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <form asp-controller="User" asp-action="Logout" method="post">
                                    <button type="submit" class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#logoutModal">
                                        <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>
                                        Logout
                                    </button>
                                </form>
                                @* <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#logoutModal">

                                    </a> *@
                            </div>
                        </li>

                    </ul>

                </nav>
                <!-- End of Topbar -->
                <!-- Begin Page Content -->
                @RenderBody()
                <!-- /.container-fluid -->

            </div>
            <!-- End of Main Content -->
            <!-- Footer -->
            <footer class="sticky-footer bg-white">
                <div class="container my-auto">
                    <div class="copyright text-center my-auto">
                        <span>Copyright &copy; Your Website 2020</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
            <!-- End of Footer -->

        </div>
        <!-- End of Content Wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- End of Page Wrapper -->
    <!-- Scroll to Top Button-->
    <a class="scroll-to-top rounded" href="#page-top">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i>
    </a>

    <!-- Logout Modal-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="logoutModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
         aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Ready to Leave?</h5>
                    <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">Select "Logout" below if you are ready to end your current session.</div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="login.html">Logout</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
    <script src="~/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
    <script src="~/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
    <script src="~/js/sb-admin-2.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Page level plugins -->
    <script src="~/vendor/chart.js/Chart.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Page level custom scripts -->
    <script src="~/js/demo/chart-area-demo.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/demo/chart-pie-demo.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the controller:

```
public class LessonController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILessonService _lessonService;
    public LessonController(ILessonService lessonService)
    {
        _lessonService = lessonService;
    }
    // GET: /<controller>/
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index([FromQuery] GetLessonsRequest request)
    {
        var lessons = await _lessonService.GetGuidelinesPaging(request);
        return Ok(lessons);
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ToeicOnlineContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MvcToeicContext")));
    services.AddApplicationLayer();
    services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
    services.AddControllers().AddFluentValidation();
    //DI
    services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ToeicOnlineContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();;
    services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<User>, UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<User, Role>>();
    services.AddTransient<UserManager<User>, UserManager<User>>();
    services.AddTransient<SignInManager<User>, SignInManager<User>>();
    services.AddTransient<RoleManager<Role>, RoleManager<Role>>();

    services.AddTransient<ILevelRepositoryAsync, LevelRepositoryAsync>();
    services.AddTransient<IClassRepositoryAsync, ClassRepositoryAsync>();
    services.AddTransient<ILessonService, LessonService>();
    services.AddTransient<ICategoryRepositoryAsync, CategoryRepositoryAsync>();
    services.AddTransient(typeof(IGenericRepositoryAsync<>), typeof(GenericRepositoryAsync<>));
    services.AddTransient<IUserService, UserService>();
    services.AddTransient<IRoleService, RoleService>();
    services.AddSwaggerExtension(Configuration);
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API v1"));
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

**Update**
It works normally with swagger, but when I use another project to call API the error like above occurs.

Comment: I think you will have to show the whole startup.cs too.

Comment: I see "GetLessonsRequest request" parameter that you are not supplying. Do you have another index action or you have a form?

Comment: What do you mean? I'm not good English. In that controller, I just have one action index

Comment: I mean do you have something like @BeginForm or <Form> in your action view?

Comment: No, In View(_layout.cshtml) just has one t link to another site

Comment: In "GetLessonsRequest" has fields keyword and id to search

Comment: I mean could you show the whole html.view ( html above and after your ancors)?

Comment: yes i updated whole view

Comment: Thank you, but it is too much for me. Sorry, but I still couldn't find any GetLessonsRequest object. I would suggest to remove  [HttpGet] from Index.

Comment: Thanks @Sergey but it still doesn't work

Comment: long shot.... but have you tried to place the the "DI" BEFORE services.AddControllers().AddFluentValidation();..... I think sometimes the order matters

Comment: Hi @JonathanAlfaro, 
nothing changed only `<a class="collapse-item" href="/Lesson/Index"> Listening </a>` working.

Comment: @tunggggg, the view and the api controller are from different projects?

Comment: Hi @mj1313, yes it different projects

Comment: Confusing, I can not reproduce your problem, maybe you can share  a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example on github, which would help troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: https://github.com/tranthanhtung-sgu/toeic.git, newest update at brach `admin-app/list-lesson`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that there is a `LessonContrller` in your `ToeicOnlineAdminApp` and a same name controller in the api project, which cause this problem. The anchor with tag helper generates the url as `api/lesson` that targets the api controller. and the anchor with `href="/Lesson/Index"` targets that controller in your current project.

Comment: I did it, you explained it very clearly, I got the point of it, thank you